# Best practice to reduce memory usage when splitting array

Tags: python, arrays, memory, numpy

I have an array that I want to split up in two halves. Because of symmetry I am only interested in keeping the left half of the array.

I can split the array in half by saying:

```
[a,b] = numpy.split(c,2)
```

where c is also an array.

Is there a way to only return the 'a' array, or alternatively removing the 'b' array from memory immediately after splitting the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy the first half with

```
a = x[len(x)//2:].copy()
```

this would need to allocate the copy and move the content (thus temporarily needing 1.5 times the memory)

Otherwise you can just say

```
a = x[len(x)//2:]
```

to get a reference to the first half, but the other part will not be removed from memory

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use **[delete](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html)** function for this aim! this is an example :

```
array=np.array([1,2,3,4])
x=len(array)/2
first_h=np.delete(array,array[x-1:])         #second half
```

Demo:

```
>>>print first_h
>>>[1,2]
```

Comment: The question is about Numpy `arrays`, who do not have a `remove` method. Your answer only works for Python `lists`.

Comment: yep , thanks for reminding ! i was wondered why i lose the up vote ! now i note ! thanks ! i edit the answer !

Comment: Not sure if this will work either. When slicing into numpy arrays, you do not make a copy, but you create a 'view' into to the original array, which keeps the big chunk of memory alive, even when you delete the original array. The docs about `np.delete` do not say a lot about this, but I guess making an explicit copy so that the original array can be freed like in @6502's answer is the way to go.

Comment: in scipy doc we read that the output of delete function is a ndarray A copy of arr with the elements specified by obj removed. Note that delete does not occur in-place. If axis is None, out is a flattened array. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think this might be best because it relies on `list`'s implementation ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement)) and I'm confident it was done right:

```
>>> r = range(10)
>>> r
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> del r[5:]
>>> r
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

See also [del statement for lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement).

Comment: The question is about Numpy `arrays`, not about Python `lists`.